# hide and show: issue while loading a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I am hidding a Flash component when my page is loading (I want it to load in the background), and then display it when it is fully loaded.

For that purpose, I have the following JavaScript code to hide it once the DOM has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#test").hide();
});
```

At this point, the flash is hidden. Then later on, I call a method that calls:

```
$("#test").show();
```

But at this point, the flash does not reappear. I tried also in the console in Firebug, and it did not work. I tried to do the same thing with a div, and it does not work as well.

If I do not hide the div/flash when it loads, but later on hide and show it in Firebug's console, then it works fine.

Does anyone please know why I do get this behavior?

EDIT:

Thank you very much,

Rudy

Comment: Need a test page or something. The problem is probably in code you're not showing us. Something to try: first hide as in the way that it doesn't work. Then in console do: $('#test').length what does it respond?

Comment: Are you using a framework to load your flash? Some frameworks don't bother loading anything if it's not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide a flash element and still have it load, you can position it outside of the visible area, instead of hiding it.  Use CSS to do this so that the element is already hidden before the `onload` event is fired.  Then, when you are ready to show the flash element, just remove the `loading` class.

CSS

```
#flash-container { position: absolute; top: ... }
#flash-container.loading { top: -1000px; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="flash-container" class="loading">
  <object ...></object>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#flash-container").removeClass("loading");
```

Also, as part of your `#flash-container` CSS definition, you'll need to define positioning for when the element is visible.

Comment: The downside here is that you can't use animations... slide up, slide down, etc.

Comment: That's irrelevant to the problem at hand.  If you set the `display` of a flash element to "none" and then back to "block," it will cause the element to be reloaded in some cases, making animation impossible anyway.

Comment: But you CAN hide and show flash using an SWFObject Jquery plugin and still have it work.

Comment: Thank you Justin and Peter!

I am going to go ahead and try Peter's solution using jQuery. It looks very appropriate for what I am doing! Thanks a lot!